# Python: Append first match of filename to a row in csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

**Update for clarity**:  I'm trying to append the value of the first match of a file name to a csv file.  I would like to append the first `fname` match in `file_label2` used to apply the `found` value to the `Suggested Label` row.  This information is retrieved from GitHub using github3.py.

In the code I have below, I do not receive an error, but I don't think it's the right way to accomplish getting the first file name match.

Sample output returned from GitHub:

```
PR Number: 123
Login: dbs
Files:
files/file-folder/media/figure01
file_label2 = figure01
files/file-folder/jsfile-to-checkin
file_label2 = jsfile
Suggested Label:  Value1
PR Number: 567
Login: dba
Files:
files/file-folder/media/figure01
file_label2 = figure01
files/file-folder/csfile-to-checkin
file_label2 = csfile
Suggested Label:  Value2
```

Desired csv output:

```
PR Number, Login, First File Found, Suggested Label
123,dbs,files/file-folder/jsfile-to-checkin, Value1
567,dba,files/file-folder/csfile-to-checkin, Value2
```

List used to match fname prefix after file split:

```
list1=["jsfile","csfile"]
list2=["css","html"]
```

Code:

```
with open(inputFile,'w') as f:
    for prs in repo.pull_requests():
        getlabels = repo.issue(prs.number).as_dict()

        labels = [labels['name'] for labels in getlabels['labels']]
        tags = ["Bug", "Blocked", "Investigate"]
        enterprisetag = [tagsvalue for tagsvalue in labels if tagsvalue in tags]
        found = "No file match"
        if enterprisetag:
            pass
        else:
            f.write("PR Number:  %s" %getlabels['number'] + '\n' + "Login: %s" %getlabels['user']['login'] + '\n' + "Files: \n")
            for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():
                fname, extname = os.path.splitext(data.filename)
                f.write(fname+'\n')
                file_label = fname.rsplit('/',1)[-1]
                if file_label.count("-") == 1:
                    file_label2 = file_label.split("-")[0]
                    f.write("file_label2: %s" %file_label2 + '\n')
                else:
                    file_label2 = "-".join(file_label.split("-",2)[:2])
                    f.write("file_label2: %s" %file_label2 + '\n')

                if [emlabel for emlabel in list1 if emlabel in file_label2]:
                    found = "Value1"
                    break
                elif [mk_label for mk_label in list2 if mk_label in file_label2]:
                    found = "Value2"
                    break
                else:
                    found = (str(None))

            f.write("Suggested Label: %s" %found + '\n')

prNum, login, firstFileFound, label = None,None,None,None
multiLineFlag = False

with open(outputFile, 'w') as w:
    w.write("PR Number, Login, First File Found, Suggested Label\n")
    for line in open(inputFile):
        line = line.strip()
        if multiLineFlag and not(firstFileFound):
            if line.startswith('file_label') and any(fileType in line for fileType in enterprise_mobility + marketplace + modern_apps + pnp + tdc + tdc_abr + unlock_insights):
                firstFileFound = prevLine
                multiLineFlag = False
            else:
                prevLine = line

        if not multiLineFlag:
            if line.startswith('PR Number: '):
                prNum = line[len('PR Number: '):]
            elif line.startswith('Login: '):
                login = line[len('Login: '):]
            elif line.startswith('Suggested Label: '):
                label = line[len('Suggested Label: '):]

            elif line.startswith('Files:'):
                multiLineFlag = True

        if all([prNum, login, firstFileFound, label]):
            w.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" %(prNum, login, firstFileFound, label))
            prNum, login, firstFileFound, label = None,None,None,None
```

Comment: `fname[0] in file_label2` returns a boolean value not a string, telling whether `fname[0]` is contained in `file_label2` (for strings, if it is a substring). Also, what do you mean by "first `fname` match in `file_label2`"?

Comment: Your if statements are testing against lists. Any non-empty list will return True.

Comment: @LauroMoura I'm looking for the first `fname` match used to make the match in `file_label2`.  If I use `row.append(fname)`, I get the complete list, some of the values in the list don't apply, but as soon as it finds the first match used for `file_label2` to append the `found` value, I would like it to append that result to a row.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @sakurashinken Yes, I saw that in testing, but this was the last thing I tried before I posted my question.

Comment: Your question is entirely confusing.  Consider rewriting it from scratch and providing example input and desired output in clear form.

Comment: I read your question (twice), I had a sip of my very strong tea (twice) and I am still confused as to what you are trying to do here. Please rephrase the thing. I understand you have a file with a list of paths (haystack.txt), and some other file with a list of words/tokens (needles.txt) You want a third file (results.txt) that contains the first line that matches in haystack.txt for each word in needles.txt - is that right or do I need to switch to coffee?

Comment: I will rewrite the question and make it more concise so it's easier to follow.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I edited the question.  Hope this helps with clarity.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  Per John's advice, I reworded the question to help with clarity.

Comment: @DBS: the edit hasn't made it clearer to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added another edit. The answer Spade gave below is the output I'm looking for in the csv file, but I'm having issues implementing it within the GitHub calls.

Comment: @EthanFurman  Thanks for putting a bounty on this.  The updated code I posted gives me mostly what I need (@Spade answer).  There's one last issue when `Suggested Label: None` for the pull request. When writing to the second file, it skips to the next pull request in the list and applies that label and uses the first file match for the `First File Found` column and then skips the next pull request in the list.  I may post another question for that issue if I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're welcome.  You should probably up-vote Spade's answer (if it's worth accepting, it's usually worth up-voting ;) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is to separate data that is spread over multiple lines or a single-line, you scan for individual properties. Once they all are found, you start over with the next record.

```
prNum, login, firstFileFound, label = None,None,None,None
multiLineFlag = False
list1 = ["jsfile","csfile"]
inputFile = '' # Provide your input filename here
outputFile = '' # Provide your output filename here
labelFound = False
with open(outputFile, 'w') as w:
    w.write("PR Number, Login, First File Found, Suggested Label\n")
    for line in open(inputFile):
        line = line.strip()
        if multiLineFlag and not(firstFileFound):
            if line.startswith('file_label') and any(fileType in line for  fileType in list1):
                firstFileFound = prevLine
                multiLineFlag = False
            else:
                prevLine = line

        if not multiLineFlag:
            if line.startswith('PR Number:'):
                prNum = line[len('PR Number: '):]
            elif line.startswith('Login:'):
                login = line[len('Login: '):]
            elif line.startswith('Suggested Label:'):
                labelFound = True
                label = line[len('Suggested Label: '):]
                print "label is %s "%label

            elif line.startswith('Files:'):
                multiLineFlag = True

        if all([prNum, login, firstFileFound, labelFound]):
            w.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" %(prNum, login, firstFileFound, label))
            prNum, login, firstFileFound, label = None,None,None,None
            labelFound=False
```

The following will work if a number of assumptions regarding your data are true.

So, for an input file that looks like:

> PR Number: 123
>   Login: dbs
>   Files:
>   files/file-folder/media/figure01
>   file_label2 = figure01
>   files/file-folder/jsfile-to-checkin
>   file_label2 = jsfile
>   Suggested Label:  Value1
>   PR Number: 423
>   Login: ddo
>   Files:
>   files/file-folder/media/figure01
>   file_label2 = figure01
>   files/file-folder/csfile2-to-checkin
>   file_label2 = csfile
>   Suggested Label:
>   PR Number: 567
>   Login: dba
>   Files:
>   files/file-folder/media/figure01
>   file_label2 = figure01
>   files/file-folder/csfile-to-checkin
>   file_label2 = csfile
>   Suggested Label:  Value2

this will return:

> PR Number, Login, First File Found, Suggested Label
>   123,dbs,files/file-folder/jsfile-to-checkin, Value1
>   423,ddo,files/file-folder/csfile2-to-checkin,
>   567,dba,files/file-folder/csfile-to-checkin, Value2

Adjustments may be necessary to cover for edge conditions.

Comment: Instead of an input file, I'm pulling this information from GitHub.  But your fix (under this will return) is exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm struggling with how to implement your fix with the GitHub calls as seen in my code to get the data to write to the csv.  `for prs in repo.pull_requests():  getlabels = repo.issue(prs.number).as_dict()` and `for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():`

Comment: @DBS Would you share the actual repo file URL or is that only accessible privately?

Comment: It's only accessible privately.  Your answer is really close to what I'm looking for.  The output I get from GitHub is the exact output you have in your input file and the return is what I'm looking for.  The code I have for going through the repo gets the necessary information, but I don't know how to substitute the calls for the input file you have.  I'm struggling on where to place the calls for writing to the csv.

Comment: Would it be possible to first write the output as a regular file, close it for writing and then open for parsing as I suggested. Are you using PyGithub or something else - If possible, edit your question to include additional details from code but with changes to the actual URLs if you need them to be private. I've been assuming `repo` is a PyGithub object but that is just an assumption.

Comment: Repo is an object of pygithub3.  Yes, writing to a regular file and then opening it for parsing will work.  I added print statements to the code to help with flow.  I don't understand changes to the actual URL.  What I can't figure out is how to write the first run of the information to the file, pr number, login, first file found and suggested label as my `if [emlabel for emlabel in enterprise_mobility if emlabel in file_label2]:` (and the elif after it) are not giving me proper results.

Comment: Getting really close.  I now have an input file that matches your example.  I'm getting stuck on this line of code: `if line.startswith('file_label') and any(fileType in line for  fileType in list1)`.  I need to go through more than one list (list1, list2, list3).  I tried to add `and`, `or`, but the output file just checks for `file_label2` in the first list (list1).  How can I adjust this statement to iterate through multiple lists?  I did a search, but didn't find anything.

Comment: That is straightforward. To check against multiple lists `list1`, `list2` and`list3` evaluate `any(fileType in line for fileType in list1+list2+list3)`. You are checking against the sum of all lists which is as good as checking against each individual list.

Comment: When `Suggested Label: None` is in the input file, the code pulls in the files under the next pull request and its label and then skips the next pull request totally.  It never writes `None` under the `Suggested Label` column. I think I need to account for this in this line: `if line.startswith('file_label') and any(fileType in line for fileType in list1+list2+list3)`?

Comment: That problem of any expected field being null can be solved using another variable that tracks the status of it being parsed. I changed the answer to introduce a variable `labelFound` which sets to True when the label line is encountered instead of an actual label being found. Hope this helps. Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: I tried your code adjustment, but it the results were still a little off, so I added this `elif` statement under the `if` statement that looks for file matches in the lists and everything is working as expected.

`elif line.startswith('Suggested Label'):`
      `firstFileFound = "No File Match"`
       `multiLineFlag = False`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what error your script got. I notice two possible error in the code that you post:

## 1

Inside the for loop `for data in repo.pull_request(prs.number).files():`

```
if [emlabel for emlabel in list1 if emlabel in file_label2]:
                found = "Value1"
```

Here `file_label2` should be a string and `emlabel` is also a string, so I think what you need is a '==' here:

```
if [emlabel for emlabel in list1 if emlabel == file_label2]:
```

## 2

When you try to append the filename:

```
      str_to_list = [x.split(" ") for x in fname.split(" ")]
      row.append(str_to_list[0])
```

Here you probably get a nested list `str_to_list=[['your/file/name']]`. Is it what you expect?

One more thing you didn't explain in your code is the parameter `repo`. Where does it come from? Is it something you get from other scripts, or do you need to parse a text file to get it?

Please explain your problem in a more concise and clearer way so that people can really help.

Answer (score -1):

I think this does most of what you need. I have made a few assumptions, like that `pull_request(number).files()` is the same as `pr.files()` from the outer loop. And I have removed some computations that I don't think were doing anything (splitting on ' ' each member of the return value of splitting on ' ', for instance).

```
#!python3
import csv
import os.path

class C:
    @property
    def number(self):
        return '12345'

    def as_dict(self):
        return {'labels':[{'name':'Foo'}],
                'login':'xyzzy',
                }

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return 'path/to/jsfile-to-checkin.js'

    def files(self):
        return [C()]

    def issue(self, num):
        return C()

    def pull_requests(self):
        return [C()]

repo = C()

INFO = 'info.csv'
INFO_LABELS = 'info-with-labels.csv'

SKIP_TAGS = set(["Bug", "Blocked", "Investigate"])

FILENAME_LABELS = {
    'csfile':'Value1',
    'jsfile':'Value1',

    'css':'Value2',
    'html':'Value2',
}

with open(INFO, 'w+', newline='') as info_file, \
        open(INFO_LABELS, 'w') as info_labels_file:

    info = csv.writer(info_file)
    info_labels = csv.writer(info_labels_file, lineterminator='\n')

    headers = 'PR Number|Login|First file found'
    info.writerow(headers.split('|'))

    label_headers = headers + '|Suggested Labels'
    info_labels.writerow(label_headers.split('|'))

    for pr in repo.pull_requests():
        pr_issue = repo.issue(pr.number).as_dict()

        labels = [labels['name'] for labels in pr_issue['labels']]

        if any(tag in SKIP_TAGS for tag in labels):
            continue

        first_file = "No file match"
        use_label = ''

        for pr_file in pr.files():
            filename = pr_file.filename.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
            basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

            name_parts = basename.split('-')
            if len(name_parts) < 3:
                file_tag = name_parts[0]
            else:
                file_tag = '-'.join(name_parts[0:2])

            for text,label in FILENAME_LABELS.items():
                if text in file_tag:
                    first_file = pr_file.filename
                    use_label = label
                    break

            if use_label:
                break

        row = [pr.number, pr_issue['login'], first_file, use_label]
        info_labels.writerow(row)
```